# b and *b works in argument list of my function exactly same. What is the difference then?

Tags: c, pointers

I use `swapCardsRandomly(b)` but when I tried `swapCardsRandomly(*b)` program still works without any problem.

What is the difference then?

```
/*
*shuffles cards randomly
*/
void shuffle( int b[][13] ) {

    int counter;
    int rand1 = rand() % 4;
    int rand2 = rand() % 13;

    b[rand1][rand2] = 1;

    counter = 2;
    while ( counter < 53 )
    {
        rand1 = rand() % 4;
        rand2 = rand() % 13;

        while ( b[rand1][rand2] != 0 )
        {
            rand1 = rand() % 4;
            rand2 = rand() % 13;
        }

        b[rand1][rand2] = counter++;
    }
    swapCardsRandomly( b );
}

//for better shuffling swap elements randomly
void swapCardsRandomly( int m[][13] ) {

    int temp;
    int rand1; 
    int rand2;

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 13; j++ )
        {
            rand1 = rand() % 4;
            rand2 = rand() % 13;

            temp = m[i][j];
            m[i][j] = m[rand1][rand2];
            m[rand1][rand2] = temp;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.  http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: 6.2 But I heard that char a[] was identical to char *a.   YOU MEAN THİS ONE?

Comment: You should probably read all of them.

Comment: Make sure you enable compiler warnings; you should see a difference...

Comment: try: `swapCardsRandomly(&b)` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-dimensional array the first element, and a pointer to the first row have the same address. This is because the first element of an array has the same address as the array. So, in your case, `b` points to the first element of an `int [][13]` array and `*b` points to the first element of a `int [13]` array that happens to be the first row of an `int [][13]` array.

The next question is why it lets you pass `*b` to `SwapCardsRandomly` when it expects `int [][13]` as an argument. The answer is that arrays, including multi-dimensional arrays, are not proper types in C, so when passed in this manner it treats them as a way to interpret a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Both `b` and `*b` have the same address (`b[0][0]`), check this:

```
int b[1][13];
printf("%p %p %p\n", (void *)b, (void *)*b, (void *)&(b[0][0]));
```

But there is a pointer type conflict with `*b`

```
demo.c:52:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘swapCardsRandomly’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
demo.c:9:7: note: expected ‘int (*)[13]’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because value-wise both `*b` and `b` are equal that is `(void*)b == (void*)(*b)` == `true`.

`b` is a two-dimentational matrix =`b[rand1][rand2]=1;`

type of matrix name `b`  is `int[][13]` that decays into address of first element that is 0<sup>th</sup> row in two dimensional array. (you can think a two dimensional array as array of one dimensional arrays).

Because `b` is address of 0<sup>th</sup> row, so `*b` decays into address of `b[0][0]` that is address of 0<sup>th</sup> element of 0<sup>th</sup>-row. Interesting is  value (magnitude) wise both are equal that is why your code works. When your call your function with `*b` or `b` argument,  address value auto typecasted into proper type `int [][13]`.

To observe it, in your code try this printf-statement:

```
printf("\n %p  %p\n", b, *b);
```

You will find both are equal!

To understand it more better with a diagram read  this: [`A[0]`, `&A`, `*A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623640/1673391) linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because both of `b` and `*b` are equal in value but are of different types i.e both of these pointer expression are of different types but points to he same memory location.

1. `b` decays to pointer to first row (0th row) and it is of type `int (*)[]`. `*b` *dereferences* the pointer expression `b` hence
2. `*b` is of type `int (*)[]`.Since that's an array type, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array object. So it's of type `int*`.

*For detailed explanation, must read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364638/2455888).*

Comment: This answer is pretty shaky.  What does "symmetrically different" mean?  What's the difference between them?

Comment: @CarlNorum; `b` is the address of first row and `*b` is the address of first element of the array `b`.