# Passing a 3 dimensional array to a function in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

Im trying to pass a 3 Dimensional array to a function.
I got this decleration of the array

```
char cube[N][N][N];
```

It's size (N) is a constant. 
I want to pass it to a function so I can work on the array in the function and change it without copying the entire array each call..

I actually want to pass a pointer to the beginning of the array and be able to put some info to the array in the function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is precisely what's going to happen automatically: you cannot force C to pass an individual array by value even if you wanted to - it will decay to a pointer. If you wanted to pass an array by value, you'd be forced to wrap an array in a `struct`, and pass that `struct` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the simplest is to just declare the parameter as `char cube[N][N][N];` or `char cube[][N][N];` in your function, and the array will be passed by pointer (yes, it's counter-intuitive, but it really is how it works.

Comment: Wow.. that was really counter-intuitive.. I was sure it'll copy the array by value :|

Comment: The counter-intuitivity is why you should use the second writing, which hints a little more about what actually happens. Alternately, you could also write it `char (*cube)[N][N]`, since that's how it's actually passed under the hood: This obscure syntax means "pointer to 2D array" (since a 3D array is just an array of 2D ones, we're actually passing a pointer to its first element), think of it as `char[N][N]* cube` only with a more bizarre syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the parameter for your function as `char cube[][N][N]` (you can omit the length of the first dimension). You can also declare it as `char (*cube)[N][N]` (in fact compiler would parse `char cube[][N][N]` as `char (*cube)[N][N]`).

> I actually want to pass a pointer to the beginning of the array and be able to put some info to the array in the function.

Now your function is expecting an argument of type `char (*)[N][N])`, i.e, pointer to a 2D array of `char`s. Either you pass `cube` (decays to the first element, i.e, `row` of the 3D array) or `&cube[0]` (pointer to the first row of the 3D array `cube`) as an argument to your function. Now any modification to this passed array (pointer to array) in the function would be reflected to the original array.

Suggested reading: Here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364638/2455888) regarding 2D arrays. It will help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the previous answers .

you can also , if you allocate that array dynamically ,pass the triple pointer `char ***cube`
, but only if you allocate it dynamically