# C++: If size of pointer int is only 4 how can it accommodate an array?

Tags: c++

Look at this program. How does ptr get everything in array? I am a little confused.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
       int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
       int *ptr = arr;

       // sizof(int) * (number of element in arr[]) is printed
       printf("Size of arr[] %d\n", sizeof(arr));

       // sizeof a pointer is printed which is same for all type 
       // of pointers (char *, void *, etc)
       printf("Size of ptr %d", sizeof(ptr));
       return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In this declaration

```
int *ptr = arr;
```

pointer `ptr` is initialized by the address of the first element of array `arr`.

An expression like this `ptr[i]` is considered by the compiler like `*(ptr + i)` where `ptr + i` results in a pointer that points to the i-th element of array `arr`

This has a consequence that instead of `ptr[i]` you can even write `i[ptr]` because in the both expressions there is used the same pointer arithmetic.

Try for example

```
std::cout << 6["Hello CMan"] << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::cout << &6["Hello CMan"] << std::endl;
```

So using pointer `ptr` that points to the first element of array `arr` and the so-called pointer arithmetic you can access any element of array arr.

The pointer does not accomodate the array. The pointer and the array occupy different memory regions. But the pointer stores the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` will "refers" to first element of the array.

Every other element will be accessed by "adding" to base pointer address value, the size of the element multiplied by the index

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is just a number representing the memory address of the start of the array. It does not contain any information about the array itself, so there is no limit on the size of the array it points to.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `ptr` is `int*` and sizeof therefore returns the number of bytes used to store a pointer in memory. It does not return the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer for this question (and may be more than that) in these bellow link:

[Are a, &a, *a, a[0], &a[0] and &a[0][0] identical pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361111/are-a-a-a-a0-a0-and-a00-identical-pointers)

[How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)