# Complex string and array declarations

Tags: c, arrays

I am studying the basics in C and I am confused about the strings and arrays.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      char arr[2][4] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
      printf("%u %u\n",arr,arr+1);
      printf("%d",*(*(arr+1)+2) );
      return 0;
    }
```

Here `arr` and `arr+1` are adjacent locations, but in the second `printf` `arr+1` goes straight to the zero index element of the second array. How is this legal? I have thought that to go to the second array it should be `&arr+1`.

---

What i learned is --> for one dimensional array:

```
  arr[7]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

here arr and &arr should not be considered same(although they print same value, but the sense of this information is completely different) . Thats why arr+1 and &arr+1 will not be same too. &arr gives the address of a data type that is a container of 7 integers thats why &arr+1 goes to the subsequent array type that is also a container of 7 integers .
so

```
arr = 5796 , &arr = 5796    (both are base address but arr is the address of    
                   1st element while &arr is the address of the whole array)
arr+1 = 5800 ,&arr+1 = (5796+(7X4))=5797+28 = 5825(this is address of some 
new array)
```

for two dimensional array the concept is same:

```
arr[2][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

now `arr` is here is also a pointer that points to array individual elements so `arr` and `arr+1` are the addresses of its successive elements (and those elements are `{1,2,3,4}` and `{5,6,7,8}`)_
and in the same way `&arr` and `&arr+1` gives the base addresses of two arrays that have 2x4=8 elements so to `&arr` and `&arr+1` are addresses of two similar sized arrays one after another.
So

```
 arr = 5796 , arr+1 = 5796+(4*3)=5796+12 = 5808 
 &arr = 5796 , &arr+1 = 5796+(4*7)=5796+ 28= 5824
```

Now we can see in 2 dimensional array to reach an individual element there are two addresses associated.

1)`ar`r (that gives which element to choose between the two inside arrays)
2)`*arr` (that gives which element in that particular element(array)

so we need to dereference two times if we want to reach to the data.

```
arr=5796(first array), *arr=5796(first element address), **arr = 1 (1st element)
arr+1=5812(second array), *(arr+1) = 5812(first element address), *(*(arr+1))=5(first element)
arr=5796,*arr=5796, *arr+1=5796+1(second element), *(*arr+1)=2 (second element)
```

now the syntax for arrays:

```
   *arr = arr[0]
   **arr = arr[0][0]
   *arr+1 = arr[0]+1
   **arr+1 = arr[0][0]+1
   *(*arr+1) = *(arr[0]+1) = arr[0][1]
   *(*(arr+1)+1) = *(arr[1]+1) = arr[1][1]
```

there are some other ways to write arrays

```
      3[arr[1]] = arr[1][3]
      -3[arr[1]] = -arr[1][3]
      *(1[arr]+2) = *(arr[1]+2) = arr[1][2]
```

the concept can be expanded to 3 dimensional array too , but this is the minimum every beginner should understand.Correct me if I am wrong anywhere conceptually or syntactically.

Comment: Read [Why is the same value outputted for `A[0]`, `&A`, and `*A`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623556/why-is-the-same-value-outputted-for-a0-a-and-a/17623640#17623640)

Comment: *`Here arr and arr+1 are adjacent locations`* No..`arr` and `arr + 1` are adjacent **rows** address. Note `arr` is not decays into address of int, not `&arr[0][0]`, but address of complete row.

Comment: you are right .. i did not saw the results correcly and misinterpreted it. arr and arr+1 are not adjacent and             arr= *arr = *(arr+0) and arr+1 = *(arr+1) in this case

Comment: Try this code `printf(" %p %p %p", (void*)&arr, (void*)arr, (void*)*arr);` you will find same output, So value wise all are equal but semantically all are diffrent. Give it a try.

Comment: Read: [What does sizeof(&array) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499) I explained for one dimensional array. and in that answer given link for two dimensional array.

Comment: @mrigendra; `arr+1 != *(arr+1)`

Comment: @haccks i printed it and values are same.

Comment: @mrigendra; Do you think that `2` and `2.0` both are equal/same?

Comment: @mrigendra I said value wise same but semantically all are different!

Comment: yes i got your point.. i was reading your answer

Comment: @mrigendra; Try to print out tha values for `arr`, `&arr`, `arr[0]`, `&arr[0]`, `*arr` and `&arr[0][0]`!

Comment: @mrigendra: you should also consider the data type. `arr` is `char[2][4]`, whilst `&arr` is `char (*)[2][4]`. Now they will both point to the same address but their types during compilation are very different ... also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3925968/1117740

Comment: @mrigendra instead of edit question add an answer and accept that +1 for self study...

Comment: valuable suggestions. i'll keep them in my mind..

Answer (score 2):

Because `arr` is a two dimensional array.

`*(*(arr+1)+2))` is equivalent to `arr[1][2]`.

Comment: what address arr+1 contain?

Comment: @mrigendra In pointer arithmetic, `+1` will add to the address the length of one element. In the case of `arr`, its element is an array of 4 `char`. So `arr+1` is the start of the second array.

Comment: when does the compiler know that the syntax actually tries to print the value of the next array element? as when it gets to print arr+1 it prints just next address of the oth element, but when it gets to print     *(*(arr+1)+2) it understands that its the next element.. getting me?

Comment: @mrigendra The compiler knows from the type of `arr`, which is `int arr[2][4]`. So the compiler knows that it's a two dimensional array and the size of each dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d",*(*(arr+1)+2) );
```

break this it into two statements

```
*(arr+1) means arr[1]
```

like this

```
*(arr[1] + 2) means arr[1][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaration

```
char arr[2][4] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

means

```
char arr[2][4] = { 
                     {1,2,3,4},   // row 0
                     {5,6,7,8}    // row 1
                  };
```

Passing the array name `arr` to `printf` means it decays to pointer to the first element (row `0`) of the array `arr[2]` and is of type `int (*)[4]` (thought 2D array as 1D array of 2 elements which are array of 4 elements each).

> I have thought that to go to the second array it should be &arr+1.

`arr + 1` points to the second element (row `1`) of the array `arr[2]` (*and not the second element of row `1` of array `arr[2][4]`*). By doing `arr + 1`, you are not adding just `1` to the pointer `arr` (after decay) but you are adding total number of bytes needed to store the elements in a row.
Let's understand this by a simple example: Consider `arr` refernce to the address `100` and size of `int` is `4`. Then `arr + 1` means your doing `100 + (4-1)*4 = 112`.
Hence dereferencing `(arr + 1)` will give entire row `1` while dereferencing `(*(arr+1)+2)` will give the 3rd element of row `1`, i.e, 7.
And also, `%u` is used for `unsigned integer`. To print address (pointer value) use `%p` specifier in your first `printf` statement.

Comment: with `%p`, address should typecast to `void*` else undefined behavior ( `%u` even wrong also.)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Without `%p` it will give you some other value.

Answer (score 0):

`arr+1` and `&arr+1` in this context are exactly the same thing, because `arr` is an array which implicitly degrades to a pointer, or have its address taken explicitly, which amounts to the same thing.

Adding 1 to the array goes to its second element, as you know.  And `arr` is an array of arrays, so its second element is the second sub-array.

If you want the second element of the first sub-array, try `arr[0]+1`, which is equivalent to `&arr[0][1]`.

Comment: i did try to print it like this if *(*(&arr+1)+2) but its  some garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing `char arr[ROW_COUNT][COLUMN_COUNT]`, `arr[row][col]` is equivalent to `address_of_arr[col + (row * ROW_COUNT)]`. Once you've wrapped your head around that it will all make a lot more sense.

`arr` and `arr+1` should not be adjacent, there should be a difference of 4 bytes. Exactly what result are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

array you using is `character` so each field take 1 byte. `arr` and `arr+1` will not be in adjacent location.

I think when you checking output of arr and arr+1 difference is 4 so you keep the integer in mind and telling it was in adjacent location.

`&arr[0]` = address of 1st element of 1st row

`&arr[1]` = address of 1st element of 2nd row

change your datatype from `char` to `int` you will understand more.

Check the output of below program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char arr[2][4] = { 1,2,3,4,
                    5,6,7,8 };

 printf("%u\n", &arr[0][0]);
 printf("%u\n", &arr[0][4]);

 printf("%u\n", &arr[1][0]);
 printf("%u\n", &arr[1][4]);

 printf("%d\n",*(*(arr+1)+2) ); // equal to arr[1][2]
 printf("%d\n", *(arr[1] + 2) );
 printf("%d\n", arr[1][2]);

 return 0;
}
```

output :

```
3214594184
3214594188
3214594188
3214594192
7
7
7
```

above program will give some warning, replace %u with %p.